# Is there a way to run three instances of WSO2 AM in one localhost?

Tags: api, wso2, token, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager and want to run three instances of it. I followed the commands of this page [offset](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-default-ports-with-offset/) and change offset, but when I log in with both or three of the Publisher and the Devportal pages, there is something wrong with Token and this error appears:
"ID token signature validation failed"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screen capture of your carbon log and he error message you are receiving?

Comment: Yes, I will send it, but  I want to mention that when I sign in with one portal and then try to sign in with another port, the previous portal is logged out.

Comment: I added the screen capture of both pages with cookies.

Comment: Is there something wrong with JSESSIONID?

Comment: This behaviour is observed due to the WSO2 stores some of the session details in the Browser and they are overlapping (due to the localhost domain). You can run multiple WSO2 API Manager servers in a single machine, however, to access the portals of each server, I would suggest using different browsers (Chrome, Chrome-Incognito, and Edge etc). If each server is configured with a unique hostname (rather than localhost), then this will not be observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is observed due to the WSO2 stores some of the session details in the Browser and they are overlapping (due to the localhost domain). If you are to run multiple WSO2 API Manager servers in a single machine and access the portals of each server, I would suggest using different browsers (Chrome, Chrome-Incognito, and Edge etc).

Furthermore, this behaviour will not be observed if each server is configured with a unique hostname (rather than localhost). In such scenarios, you can use a single browser to access the portals of each deployed server in your environment.